# Java Swing: Layout Manager like "North" in BorderLayout needed

Tags: java, swing

I would like a Layout Manager like the Border Layout Manager, except only having a single region: North.

The North region of the Border Layout Manager is working fine for me (i.e. taking up the correct space), but, the center is occupying all available space (see the blue area below). Ideally I would like the center to occupy zero space.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Example 1 of 2 (pic)

[image: example]

Example 2 of 2 (code)

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            JFrame j = new JFrame("Test");
        WorkBench right = new WorkBench();

        JScrollPane sp 
            = new JScrollPane(
                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        sp.setAutoscrolls(false);
        sp.setViewportView(right);

        j.getContentPane().add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        right.addPortal(getNewPortalPane());
        right.addPortal(getNewPortalPane());

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() {
                sp.getViewport().setViewPosition(new java.awt.Point(0, 0));
            }
        });


        // center the jframe, then make it visible
        j.setSize(800, 600);
        j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        j.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }


public static JPanel getNewPortalPane()
{
    JEditorPane html_box = new JEditorPane();
    html_box.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
    html_box.setOpaque(true);
    html_box.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    html_box.setContentType("text/html");

    String htmlString = "<html>\n"
        + "<body>\n"
        + "<h1>Welcomfve!  sdsdsdsdsd sdsdsd sdsd sdsd sdsd </h1>\n"
        + "<h2>This is an H2 header. sdsdsdsdsd sdsdsd sdsd sdsd sdsd </h2>\n"
        + "<p>This is some sample text  sdsdsdsdsd sdsdsd sdsd sdsd sdsd </p>\n"
        + "<p><a href=\"http://dsfsdfdf.com/blog/\">sdfsdfsdf blog</a></p>\n"
        + "</body>\n";

    html_box.setText(htmlString);


    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.setBackground(Color.blue);
    p.add(html_box, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    return p;
}

public static class WorkBench extends JPanel implements Scrollable
{
    private Box vertical_box = null;

    public WorkBench()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.vertical_box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        add(this.vertical_box , BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void addPortal(JPanel portal)
    {
        this.vertical_box.add(portal);

        validate();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() 
    {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }


    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(
            Rectangle visibleRect,
            int orientation, 
            int direction) 
    {
        return 20;
    }


    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(
            Rectangle visibleRect,
            int orientation, 
            int direction)
    {
        return 60;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() 
    {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()
    {
         if (getParent() instanceof JViewport)
         {
             return (((JViewport)getParent()).getHeight() > getPreferredSize().height);
         }

         return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Okay...so that would mean that the `NORTH` position would act like the `CENTER` position...

Comment: I see what you're saying, but the North region is currently occupying the minimum required space needed for its content, so if I could get the same effect, without a Center region that's taking up all the space- see the blue area above - space I would like to fill with other things.

Comment: `GridBagLayout`, use the `GridBagConstraints` `weightx` set to `1`, `gridwidth` set to `REMAINDER` and `fill` set to `HORIZONTAL`...

Comment: That sort of works, but now I see the following: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vdxlV.png. Before I resize the window, the panels using the GridBadLayout are too small. After I resize the window, these panels are too narrow, and don't fill the width.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Good point! I've added a code example.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Should it not be `weighty`?

Comment: Tried setting weighty to 1 instead, but no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant solution somewhere, but what I've found works is using `BorderLayout.NORTH` to add an inner panel, set the inner panel's layout to `BoxLayout` using `PAGE_AXIS`, and then add components to the inner panel. So in your example it would be (edited to fix scrollbar) :

```
public class test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      public void run() {
        JFrame j = new JFrame("Test");
        WorkBench right = new WorkBench();

        final JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        sp.setAutoscrolls(false);
        sp.setViewportView(right);

        j.getContentPane().add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        right.addPortal(getNewPortalPane());
        right.addPortal(getNewPortalPane());

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

          public void run() {
            sp.getViewport().setViewPosition(new java.awt.Point(0, 0));
          }
        });

        // center the jframe, then make it visible
        j.setSize(800, 600);
        j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        j.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public static JPanel getNewPortalPane() {
    JEditorPane html_box = new JEditorPane();
    html_box.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
    html_box.setOpaque(true);
    html_box.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    html_box.setContentType("text/html");

    String htmlString = "<html>\n"
        + "<body>\n"
        + "<h1>Welcomfve!  sdsdsdsdsd sdsdsd sdsd sdsd sdsd </h1>\n"
        + "<h2>This is an H2 header. sdsdsdsdsd sdsdsd sdsd sdsd sdsd </h2>\n"
        + "<p>This is some sample text  sdsdsdsdsd sdsdsd sdsd sdsd sdsd </p>\n"
        + "<p><a href=\"http://dsfsdfdf.com/blog/\">sdfsdfsdf blog</a></p>\n"
        + "</body>\n";

    html_box.setText(htmlString);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.setBackground(Color.blue);
    p.add(html_box, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    return p;
  }

  public static class WorkBench extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

    private final JPanel inner;

    public WorkBench() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      inner = new JPanel();
      inner.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inner, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      add(inner, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public void addPortal(JPanel portal) {
      inner.add(portal);
      validate();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
      return getPreferredSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
        int orientation, int direction) {
      return 20;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
        int orientation, int direction) {
      return 60;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
      if (getParent() instanceof JViewport) {
        return (((JViewport) getParent()).getHeight() > getPreferredSize().height);
      }

      return false;
    }
  }
}
```